# About Connection Speed

Tags: performance, connection, speed

I have this problem for months and I couldn't solve this. It's really weird problem for me.

I have a cable modem NetMaster and additionally TP-Link Router (to extend wireless area).

There are three laptops and four smart phones in home, and there is no problem about connection speed except one laptop.

When the laptop connects to the router(TP-Link), there is no problem, download speed is about 20mbps. But when the laptop connects to modem (NetMaster), download speed is about 0.2mbps. There is no problem when the other devices connect to the modem. Just one laptop is affecting to problem. By the way, the laptop has two operating systems (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04LTS) The problem occures when the Windows 7 active, there is no problem in Ubuntu.

I've reset both modem and router, but It didn't solve the problem. I've check the firewall, antivirus vs. there is nothing to cause a problem.

As a result, I can't solve this problem. What can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try updating/reinstalling your WLAN drivers for Windows 7?

Comment: Yes I have tried it many times. There is no problem with other connections.